# PHP the_content() function wordpress errors

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a function that allows me to SPLIT `the_content` in wordpress using the more `<!--more-->` tag in the `posts` field.
However, I don't know what I'm doing and seem to be making a mess

In my functions.php I have the following code.

```
function split_content() {

    global $more;
    $more = true;
    $content = preg_split('/<span id="more-d+"></span>/i', get_the_content('more'));
    for($c = 0, $csize = count($content); $c < $csize; $c++) {
        $content[$c] = apply_filters('the_content', $content[$c]);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

In my homepage.php I have replaced the_content with the following function

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php
        $content = split_content();
        echo '<div>', array($content[0]), '</div>';
        ?>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?
?>
```

This system gives 2 errors :

> Warning: preg_split() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   C:\MAMP\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Test\wp-vanilla\functions.php
>   on line 125
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\MAMP\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Test\wp-vanilla\page-homepage.php
>   on line 41

Can anyone help? I've tried various combinations.

Answer (score 1):

maybe u need use this function [get_extended() WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_extended)

it Return Values

(array) 
    Post before ('main') and after ('extended').

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this :

```
$morestring = '<!--more-->';
$explode_content = explode( $morestring, $post->post_content );
$content_before = apply_filters( 'the_content', $explode_content[0] );
$content_after = apply_filters( 'the_content', $explode_content[1] );
```

Hope it helps you some extent.

Comment: thanks jenis,   This does help .... does the above code get placed in functions.php?   what would i need to place in my index.php , i.e. were I would like the content to show up?